# No route to host when connect() from client

Tags: sockets, server, tcp, client

I made a simple TCP server and client based on
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tcp-server-client-implementation-in-c/

I found compile errors if I compile the example code as is.
So I modified the original code a little bit.
This is the server code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 12345
#define MAX 80

/* Function designed for chat between client and server */
void func(int sockfd)
{
   char buff[MAX];
   int n;

   for (;;)
   {
      bzero(buff, MAX);

      /* read the message from client and copy it in buffer */
      read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));

      /* print buffer which contains the client contents */
      printf("From client : %s\t To client : ", buff);

      bzero(buff, MAX);
      n = 0;

      /* copy server message in the buffer */
      while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
         ;

      /* and send that buffer to client */
      write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));

      /* if msg contains "Exit" then server exit and chat ended */
      if (strncmp("exit", buff, 4) == 0)
      {
         printf("Server Exit ....\n");
         break;
      }
   }
}


int main()
{
   int sockfd, connfd, len;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

   struct sockaddr_in *sa;
   struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
   char *addr;
   int family;

   if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1)
   {
      perror("getifaddrs");
      exit(0);
   }

   for (ifa = ifaddr ; ifa != NULL ; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
   {
      if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
         continue;

      family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family;
      if (family == AF_INET)
      {
         sa = (struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_addr;
         addr = inet_ntoa(sa->sin_addr);
         printf("Interface : %s, Address : %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, addr);
      }
   }

   /* socket creation and verification */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfd == -1)
   {
      printf("socket creation failed...\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("socket successfully created...\n");
   }

   bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   /* assign IP and PORT */
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

   if ((bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0)
   {
      printf("socket bind failed...\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Socket successfully binded...\n");
   }

   /* Now server is ready to listen and verification */
   if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0)
   {
      printf("Listen failed ...\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Server listening ...\n");
   }

   len = sizeof(cli);


   /* Accept the data packet from client and verification */
   connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli, &len);
   if (connfd < 0)
   {
      printf("Server accept failed...\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("Server accept the client...\n");
   }

   /* Function for chatting between client and server */
   func(connfd);

   /* After chatting, close the socket */
   close(sockfd);
}
```

And this is the client code.

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX 80
#define PORT 12345

void func(int sockfd)
{
   char buff[MAX];
   int n;

   for (;;)
   {
      bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
      printf("Enter the string : ");

      n = 0;
      while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n')
         ;

      write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
      bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));

      read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
      printf("From Server : %s", buff);

      if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0)
      {
         printf("Client Exit ...\n");
         break;
      }
   }
}


int main()
{
   int sockfd, connfd;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

   /* socket create and verification */
   sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   if (sockfd == -1)
   {
      printf("socket creation failed...\n");
      exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("socket successfully created...\n");
   }

   bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   /* assign IP, PORT */
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.203");
   servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

   /* connect the client socket to server socket */
   if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0)
   {
      printf("connection with the server failed ...[%s]\n", strerror(errno));
      exit(0);
   }
   else
   {
      printf("connected to the server ...\n");
   }

   /* function for chat */
   func(sockfd);

   /* close the socket */
   close(sockfd);
   return 0;
}
```

And I ran server on 192.168.1.203 and client on 192.168.1.219.
I could ping between 192.168.1.203 and 192.168.1.219.
And iptables are all cleared. (ran iptables -F).

But from client side, I see "No route to host" error message.
This is the message from server side when I execute the server program.

```
# ./server
Interface : lo, Address : 127.0.0.1
Interface : ens37, Address : 192.168.1.203
socket successfully created...
Socket successfully binded...
Server listening ...
```

And the below is the message from the client side.

```
# ./client
# ./client
socket successfully created...
connection with the server failed ...[No route to host]
```

It would be great if somebody pointed out something I did wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the *actual* code you are using.

Comment: Updated the original question with the exact source code I am using.

Comment: I see problems with your `func()`'s, but you are not getting that far. I don't see any problem with how your client is `connect()`'ing to the server, implying a likely network issue. But your `printf()`'s when `connect()` fails are wrong. The 1st `printf()` *may* change `errno` before you read it. Never make a system call after a failure and before reading `errno`. In this case, either save `errno` to a local variable before the 1st `printf()`, or else merge the two `printf()`'s together (and then consider using `perror()` instead of `printf(strerror())`).

Comment: I also suggest having your server print out the IPs from `getifaddrs()` or equivalent function, just to make sure the server PC is really assigned the IP you are expecting.

Comment: I made another quick updates of server.c and client.c with getifaddrs().

Comment: the code for `connect()` and `bind()/listen()/accept()` looks fine to me, so the problem has to be outside of the code. Which means this is not a programming issue, so try asking on [sf] instead.

Comment: I also now think it will be network issue or server issue. I moved this server/client program to another computers and works fine.

Comment: I tested a little more. So far I found if I run this server and client program on CentOS 8 computers. This problem occurred. But if I run the same program on Ubuntu computer, it worked without the problem. When I tested, I cleared iptables and disable SELINUX.

Answer (score 0):

I tested several idea and finally found the reason.
When I stopped firewalld from CentOS8 systems using "systemctl
stop firewalld".
Then, everything works well.